# jQuery lightbox multiple items to look like Mac dashboard

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, lightbox

I'm wondering if it's possible in any existing lightbox to pop up a look similar to the mac dashboard where multiple divs could be "on" in the front with the main webpage with a gray overlay.

Basically something where a user clicks an icon on the main webpage to call, and then 4 separate content boxes are popped on top, but not in a window like a gallery.

I'm thinking the top background used could be set to transparent and the individual items could be divs on the popped area, but before I reinvent the wheel, I thought I'd see if there's something like this that I just haven't found in my searches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using colorbox with a background behind my divs. It doesn't look like the mac with items having the bg behind them showing between them, but after talking to the designer I'm working with, that wasn't something they really needed anyhow. I think it MAY be possible changing some of the CSS though for the bg of the "popped" window. Colorbox seems to be pretty nice about making it clear what the CSS is doing and there are multiple example skins.